# Recommended .gitignore for sharepoint solutions

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-farm, custom-web-parts, source-control

I've inherited a heavily customized SharePoint 2013 environment that makes heavy use of farm solutions.

I'm trying to implement Git as a source control for our environment so that we can have better control over change management and disaster recovery.

I'm having some issues where the dynamic manifest files are not being carried up when pushing a branch up to my Git repo which causes me to lose my file declarations in my packages and features when I pull the repo back down from origin.

Is my issue with my .gitignore or should I go away from dynamically generated manifest files? I am using [GitHub's visual studio git ignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore).

Comment: It is specific to sharepoint though. I am having issues with my sharepoint project files not maintaining changes through source control.. How is that not sharepoint related?

Comment: Asked on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641056/issues-with-sharepoint-project-files-not-persisting-through-git-push-pull